# how to change parameters in NDSolve?

Tags: differential-equations

I want to solve a PDE with parameters chosen based on the sign of derivative. For instance in the following PDE

```
r = 0.0
NDSolveValue[{D[V[S, t], t] + rSD[V[S, t], S] + 1/2 sigma^2 S^2 D[V[S, t],
  {S, 2}] - r V[S, t] == 0, V[S, 2.0] == Max[S - 100, 0], V[0, t] == 0, V[200, t] == 100},
 V, {S, 0, 200}, {t, 0, 2.0}];
```

I want to use `sigma = 0.20` when `D[V[S, t], {S, 2}] > 0`
and `sigma = 0.30` when `D[V[S, t], {S, 2}] <= 0`

Is it possible to do that in `NDSolve` or do I need to write my own FD routine?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 0) Browse the [common pitfalls](http://goo.gl/zpsUsd) question 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq]! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: You might define `sigma` in terms of [`Piecewise`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Piecewise.html).

Comment: You can format inline code and code blocks by selecting the code and clicking the `{}` button above the edit window. The edit window help button `?` is also useful for learning how to format your questions and answers. You may also find this [this meta Q&A](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful

Answer (score 2):

Notwithstanding the starting value of `sigma`, `D[V[S, t], {S, 2}]` looks always positive

```
sigma = .3;
r = 0;
nd = NDSolve[{
   D[V[S, t],t] + r S D[V[S, t],S] + sigma^2 S^2 D[V[S, t],{S, 2}]/2 - r V[S, t] == 0,
   V[S, 2] == Max[S - 100, 0],
   V[0, t] == 0,
   V[200, t] == 100}, V, {S, 0, 200}, {t, 0, 2}]

Plot3D[D[V[S, t], {S, 2}] /. nd[[1]] /. S -> s, {s, 0, 200}, {t, 0, 2}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

And for starting `sigma = .2`:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: this is not correct. I don't want two different solutions for sigma = 0.2 and sigma = 0.3. While iterating the pde if D[V[S,t],{S,2}] is positive i want to use sigma = 0.2 and otherwise sigma = 0.3

Comment: I understand in this case D[V[S,t],{S,2}]  is always positive throughout the grid. If I change the payoff to something like   V[S, 2] == Max[S - 100, 0]-Max[S-110,0],
   V[0, t] == 0,
   V[200, t] == 10}, then you will observe positive and negative signs for second derivative. But as of now I am just looking for a method to control parameter based on the derivative calculation while iterating the PDE

Comment: Plain and simple question. How to change parameter values of PDE (sigma or r) based on the derivative being calculated at each step?

Comment: 1) AFAIK yes, this is mostly correct. 2) Your example design simply doesn't show up the characteristics you wanted  to appear 3) Plain and simple: design a better example and edit your question so somebody else don't need to do it

Comment: @coffee, have you looked into `Piecewise[]`?